# Appending or storing a for loop in r in a list

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm essentially calculating probabilities that I hope to plot.  My goal was to put these in a list or a vector, but I've been having trouble doing so.   I wrote this for loop and I can print out all the values, but I can't seem to store them in a list.

```
probs <- list()
for (i in seq(0,1,length=100)) {
  append(probs,1 - mean(rbinom(100000,6,i)==4))
}
```

I've been able to print my results (see below), but not store them.

```
for (i in seq(0,1,length=100)) {
  print(1 - mean(rbinom(100000,6,i)==4))
}
```

When I see what is in the list of probabilities I get an empty `list`.  Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` doesn't mutate the list, it just returns a new `list`, which gets lost because it's not saved anywhere.

Try this:

```
probs <- list()
for (i in seq(0,1,length=100)) {
  probs <- append(probs,1 - mean(rbinom(100000,6,i)==4))
}
```

or use a `vector` instead:

```
probs <- vector()
for (i in seq(0,1,length=100)) {
  probs <- append(probs,1 - mean(rbinom(100000,6,i)==4))
}
probs # obviously it varies per execution
  [1] 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99999 0.99994 0.99988 0.99981 0.99971 0.99946
 [10] 0.99921 0.99864 0.99824 0.99758 0.99674 0.99573 0.99466 0.99271 0.99031
 [19] 0.98862 0.98669 0.98389 0.98074 0.97781 0.97457 0.97028 0.96523 0.96225
 [28] 0.95483 0.94936 0.94447 0.93965 0.93278 0.92486 0.91704 0.90908 0.90305
 [37] 0.89365 0.88608 0.87596 0.86834 0.85762 0.84787 0.83998 0.82830 0.81918
 [46] 0.80843 0.80078 0.78881 0.77933 0.77061 0.76032 0.75416 0.74201 0.73520
 [55] 0.72575 0.71545 0.70855 0.70364 0.69809 0.69209 0.68604 0.68294 0.67610
 [64] 0.67491 0.67463 0.67226 0.67048 0.66950 0.67413 0.67556 0.67900 0.68065
 [73] 0.68591 0.69526 0.70135 0.70930 0.71619 0.72765 0.73874 0.75130 0.76355
 [82] 0.77658 0.79165 0.80553 0.82090 0.83728 0.84947 0.86944 0.88331 0.90126
 [91] 0.91595 0.92875 0.94334 0.95669 0.96918 0.97930 0.98813 0.99400 0.99856
[100] 1.00000
```